# regex to extract all numbers with different lengths and special characters

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

```
text1=""" my acc no is 1234 5678.I pay 123$ as an interest @ 14.9% starting from 12/07/19.My debit number is 123-45666-789-112"""
```

I want output to have all numbers like `1234 5678`, `123$`, `14.9%`, `12/07/19`, `123-45666-789-112`

Code am trying to run is giving partial results. Please help me out

```
import re

reg="\d{1,}[^a-zA-Z]?\d{1,}?[^a-zA-Z]?\d?"

gc=re.compile(reg)
number = gc.findall(text1)
print(number)
['1234 567', '123$', '14.9%', '12/07', '19.', '123-456', '66-789', '112']
```

Also how do i extract if I want two words before number?
i.e acc no is 1234 5678 etc..

Answer (score 2):

To get full results, you can use the following regex :

```
(?:\d+[ $%./-]?)+
```

It capture sequences of number possibly separated by a single consecutive numeric separator. This captures dates, numbers with single spaces as thundreds separators and currency/percentage signs, but will avoid matching `1. 2` in `sentence 1. 2nd sentence` and leaves the possibility to use multiples spaces to separate numbers.

To include the two previous words, you can use this one :

```
[^\d ]+ [^\d ]+ (?:\d+[ $%./-]?)+
```

It just captures two sequences of non-numeric characters separated by space before continuing with the previous regex.

(note that in the case of the account number, it will only capture "no is ")

[Try it online !](https://ideone.com/lGHvVK)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this regexp code if you wish to match separately

```
\d{1,2}[/\s\.-]\d{1,2}[/\s\.-](\d{2}|\d{4})\b|\d{2,4}[.]\d{1,4}[%]|\d{1,5}[$]|\d{1,4}[-]\d{1,8}[-]\d{1,4}[-]\d{1,8}|\d{1,8}[\s]\d{1,8}
```

this code matches date properly if you pass date as 19/05/193 it won't match

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `r"([\w]{0,} ?[\w]{0,} ?[^\d ]+) ((?:(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)+[ $%/-]?)+)"`

Example

```
match = re.search(r"([\w]{0,} ?[\w]{0,} ?[^\d ]+) ((?:(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)+[ $%/-]?)+)", subject, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
if match:
    text = match.group(1)
    number = match.group(2)
else:
    result = ""
```

Results:

```
Match 1:    acc no is 1234 5678      
Group 1:    acc no is   
Group 2:    1234 5678   
Match 2:    I pay 123$  
Group 1:    I pay       
Group 2:    123$        
Match 3:    an interest @ 14.9%     
Group 1:    an interest @
Group 2:    14.9%       
Match 4:     starting from 12/07/19     
Group 1:     starting from  
Group 2:    12/07/19        
Match 5:    debit number is 123-45666-789-112       
Group 1:    debit number is  
Group 2:    123-45666-789-112
```